# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de una variable en un bucle cada 5 repeticiones?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que mi bucle cambie cuando el conteo de un valor sea múltiplo de 5 o del múltiplo que yo quiera.

Éste es mi código:

```
var multiplo = ["aguacate ","albaricoque ","ananá","arándano","arándano ","banana","cereza ","ciruela","higo","kiwi","lima","limón","mandarina","mango","manzana","maracuyá","melocotón ","melón","membrillo",];
var cont = 0;
var valorc = "";
var limite = 5;

function parar() {


var e = setInterval( function() {

switch(cont) {
    case 1:
        valorc = multiplo[0];
    break;

    case limite * 1:
        valorc = multiplo[1];  
    break;

    case limite * 2:
        valorc = multiplo[2];
    break;

    case limite * 3:
        valorc = multiplo[3];
    break;

    case limite * 4:
        valorc = multiplo[4];   
    break;

    case limite * 5:
        valorc = multiplo[5];   
    break;

}       
        cont++;
        console.log(cont)
        console.log(valorc)
    if (cont === 100) {

    clearInterval(e);
    } 

}, 300);

}
parar();
```

Ese código lo hace perfectamente, mi problema es que tengo que escribir mucho código por si quiero más de 100. En caso de que quiera un conteo de 1000 no quiero escribir todo ese código.

He intentado usando un `switch`:

```
switch(cont) {
    case 1:
        valorc = multiplo[0];
    break;

    case limite * 1:
        valorc = multiplo[1];  
    break;

    case limite * 2:
        valorc = multiplo[2];
    break;

    case limite * 3:
        valorc = multiplo[3];
    break;

    case limite * 4:
        valorc = multiplo[4];   
    break;

    case limite * 5:
        valorc = multiplo[5];   
    break;
```

Me gustaría saber si hay una forma que se pueda hacer, intenté de esta manera pero siempre me sale el último valor.

```
for( var i=cont;i<multiplo.length; i++ ) {
switch(cont) {
    case 1:
        valorc = multiplo[i];
    break;

    case limite * 1:
        valorc = multiplo[i];  
    break;

    case limite * 2:
        valorc = multiplo[i];
    break;

    case limite * 3:
        valorc = multiplo[i];
    break;

    case limite * 4:
        valorc = multiplo[i];   
    break;

    case limite * 5:
        valorc = multiplo[i];   
    break;

}}
```

y esta otra:

```
    for( var i=cont;i<multiplo.length; i++ ) {
switch(cont) {
    case limite * cont:
        valorc = multiplo[i];
    break;

}}
```

Me gustaría saber si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer que funcione sin escribir tanto código para ahorrar tiempo y demás. Estoy abierto a cualquier solución.

Comment: Necesitas utilizar el operador de congruencia %

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa el operador módulo para simplificar tu código. En JavaScript el operador módulo es `%` y lo que hace es devolver el resto de la división entera de los operadores. Por ejemplo, `23 % 5 = 3` y `25 % 5 = 0`.

Entonces en tu código lo que podrías hacer es algo como esto:

```
for( var i=cont;i<multiplo.length; i++ ) {
    if (cont % 5 === 0) valorc = multiplo[i];
```

Cada vez que el resultado del módulo con 5 sea 0 (es decir, cada vez que sea un múltiplo de 5), cambia el valor de la variable que quieras.